# Get Google map embed url from regular link

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I recently came across a site[image: Valid HTML] where you can drag the regular Google map url to the their page and it will automatically embed it via iframe. I read the Google Maps Embed API and it looks like there's no way to do this. I'm not sure if this can be achieved using regex to extract the parameters.

```
// Sample https://www.google.com/maps/@37.3321023,-121.9035969,14z

$(button).click(function() {
   reg-url = $('#inputbox').val();
   convert();
});

function convert() {
    embedid = //get param from reg-url
    $('.wrapper').html("<iframe src='https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb="+embedid+"'>");
}
```

So basically I want to create a jquery function that will convert regular map url to embed url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function GoogleMapsURLToEmbedURL(GoogleMapsURL)
{
    var coords = /\@([0-9\.\,\-a-zA-Z]*)/.exec(GoogleMapsURL);
    if(coords!=null)
    {
        var coordsArray = coords[1].split(',');
        return "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d20000!2d"+coordsArray[1]+"!3d"+coordsArray[0]+"!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1486486434098";
    }
}
```

In your sample:-

```
https://www.google.com/maps/@37.3321023,-121.9035969,14z
```

After the '@', 37.3321023 is one co-ordinate, -121.9035969 is the second, and 14z is the zoom.

I've done the co-ordinates for you, all you'd need to do is write some if's to work out turning the zoom into an integer for the embed (I've set it to always be 20000, which looks to be around the 14th zoom level according to the web interface.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you! I'm just wondering, there's gotta be a way so I don't have to write 100 lines of conditional statements for the value of zoom. Perhaps we can multiply coordsArray[2] to some number. I just can't get the pattern. Here's the data http://pastebin.com/A4P0mrSj

Comment: @VianneYuZhèng It looks like zoom levels are based on their screen resolution, 1 fits 1 map tile on their screen (which is why it seems so disjointed)

http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/7480

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

Extract coordinates from a regular link

```
export const getCoordinatesFromGoogleMapURL = (url: string) => {
  if (!url) {
    return undefined
  }
  const urlParts = url.split('/@')[1]?.split(',')

  if (!(urlParts && urlParts?.length > 1)) {
    return undefined
  }

  const gpsX = parseFloat(urlParts[0])
  const gpsY = parseFloat(urlParts[1])

  if (isNaN(gpsX) || isNaN(gpsY)) {
    return undefined
  }

  return [gpsX, gpsY] as [number, number]
}
```

Generate embed url from coordinates:

```
export const generateGoogleMapEmbedUrl = (coordinates: [number, number]) => {
  if (!coordinates) {
    return undefined
  }

  const baseUrl = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/streetview"
  const coordinatesString = `${String(coordinates[0])},${String(coordinates[1])}`
  const url = `${baseUrl}?key=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}&location=${coordinatesString}`

  return url
}
```

Finally we can put it together:

```
export function convertToEmbedURL(url: string): string {
  const coordinates = getCoordinatesFromGoogleMapURL(url)
  const embedUrl = generateGoogleMapEmbedUrl(coordinates)

  return embedUrl;
}
```

You can read the official docs to find out more about params etc: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/embedding-map#streetview_mode

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to Converting from a google map url to embeded link for the iframe src attribute .

here i have an iframe that points to a location on google maps , and after 5 seconds , the function "fromLinkToEmbeded" will get the google map url link that is saved on the maplink variable and will change get the coordinates to inject them in the src attribute of the iframe element

```html
<div>
    <iframe id="mapsFrame"
        src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d26081.217527432873!2d-0.663236!3d35.2026779!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0xd7f003333a9b2b5%3A0x2a626a504a41aa51!2sRailway%20station!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sdz!4v1684402795522!5m2!1sen!2sdz" 
        width="450" height="150" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"
        referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
</div>


<script>
 var maplink = "https://www.google.com/maps/@37.3321023,-121.9035969,14z";

    
    function fromLinkToEmbeded(googleMapsLink) {

        var cordinates = googleMapsLink.split("@")[1];
        var cordX = cordinates.split(',')[0];
        var cordY = cordinates.split(',')[1];
        var zoom = cordinates.split(',')[2].split("z")[0];

        var iframe = document.getElementById('mapsFrame');
        iframe.src = "https://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + cordX + ", " +
            cordY +
            "&z=" + zoom +
            "&output=embed";

    }
setTimeout(() => {
  fromLinkToEmbeded(maplink);
    }, 5000);
</script>
```